# Как отобразить данные из List<> в xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Как я могу вывести данные из List<> в xaml файле?

```
public class Fruit
    {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
        public string Price{ get; set; }
    }



public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        List<Fruit> fruits= new List<Fruit>()
        {
            new Fruit(){Name= "Apple" , Image = ImageSource.FromFile("apple.png")},
            new Fruit(){Name= "Orange" , Image = ImageSource.FromFile("orange.png")},
            new Fruit(){Name= "Pear" , Image = ImageSource.FromFile("pear.png")},
            new Fruit(){Name= "Mandarin" , Image = ImageSource.FromFile("mandarine.png")}
        };


<ScrollView x:Name="scrollview" Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackLayout x:Name="stacklayoutscrollview">
            ??????
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: посмотрите [Сочетание XAML и C#. Привязка к списку](https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/3.16.php)

Comment: Любой `ItemsControl` (`ListBox`, `ListView`. сам `ItemsControl`) берите и привязывайте его.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял вы хотите увидеть список ваших элементов на странице. Для это используйте контрол `ListView` (инструкция на [русском](https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/3.16.php) и на [английском](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/))

Реализация конкретно вашего примера:

```
<ScrollView x:Name="scrollview" Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackLayout x:Name="stacklayoutscrollview">
        <ListView x:Name="fruitList"
              HasUnevenRows="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding fruits}" >
              <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ImageCell
                        ImageSource="{Binding Image }"
                        Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```